# Finding the macOS Bluetooth libary / settings application

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I'm trying to reverse engineer the macOS Bluetooth library and settings application to find out how it displays the battery level of the Apple AirPods in the menu bar.

I have been looking for a while, but I can't seem to find out where they are hiding... (I already looked in the applications folder, the library/extensions folder, ...)

Does anyone know where can I find the Bluetooth library and maybe even the settings.app?

Answer (score 0):

/System/Library/CoreServices/BluetoothUIServer.app